Repeated Measures vs. Independent ANOVA for Comparing Machine Learning Models Trained on Participant-Specific Data
I have a machine learning project where I train multiple models (e.g., Model A, Model B, Model C) on a single dataset containing data from multiple participants. Each participant's data is used to train all three models, resulting in participant-specific instances of each model (e.g., participant 1 has Model A1, B1, C1).
I evaluate the accuracy of each model (A, B, C) for each participant on a held-out test set.
My goal is to compare the overall accuracy of these models (A, B, C) across all participants. I'm not currently interested in any interaction effects.
Should I use a repeated measures ANOVA or an independent ANOVA for this analysis?
Assumptions:
We assume that the necessary assumptions for ANOVA (normality, homogeneity of variance) are met. If not, we are prepared to use a non-parametric alternative.

Why do you need a statistical test? Why not just report the accuracy and/or summary metrics, e.g. which model had the highest accuracy / lowest log-loss / highest AUC / etc? Is this an XY problem?

Doing a statistical test is generally expected in the field I am working in (clinical-adjacent field). The motivation for this is simple: if I propose a solution, I must show that it is statistically better than existing solutions across a wide enough range of participants. Average accuracy/F1 score (or any measures) is generally not accepted as sufficient outside of preliminary studies.

I understand; if you're going to use an anova I think it should be repeated measures as the samples are clearly not independent, but in my experience t-tests/anova aren't 'enough' for publication as it's only comparing means / variance. I've had a positive responses from clinicians (oncologists) when I've compared AUC curves for different treatments (p-values calculated using Delong's test) and coxph modelling / forest plots, but without more context it's difficult to answer your question sorry
